# Async/await: a correct way to make background task non-blocking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

> EDIT: from OP's comment, the goal is 
>   **non-blocking background task so that the rest remain responsive**

Say I have a function like this:

```
void OnFrameSampleAcquired(VideoCaptureSample sample)
{  
    //Some code here

    //Here I want to introduce an Asynchrnous process
    ProcessAsynchronously(_latestImageBytes);

    //some more code here
}
```

In the point commented, I want to introduce a call to an asynchronous function. 
Now, I **can not** modify `OnFrameSampleAcquired` (meaning I can not make it "async").
How can I do this?

I am thinking

```
async void ProcessAsynchronously(byte[] image)
{
    await Process1(image);
    await Process2(image);
    // ...
}
```

or `async Task ProcessAsynchronously(byte[] image)`

where ProcessX are also declared as `async`

Is this a good approach?

Thanks for any insight, since my practical experience with asynchronous processing is very few.

Comment: Well, that does not make sense to me, really. What is the advantage over calling those methods synchronously in this case?

Comment: could you explain on a higher level of abstraction, what effect/output you need to achieve here? Is it about parallel processing, or non-blocking background tasks, while some UI remains responsive?

Comment: It always depends. In this case on Process1() and Process2(). Are they really async ? Because processing an image in-memory sounds more CPU bound than I/O bound.

Comment: @dlatikay Non-blocking background task so that the rest remain responsive

Comment: I guess in that case `//some more code here` should be executed in a callback or continuation. Are you allowed to do that? Or is that technically impossible?

Comment: Why exactly you caanot add async to OnFrameSampleAcquired? That does not change signature of that function. I mean `async void OnFrameSampleAcquired`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that depends, since the function could be asynchronously streaming the image from the source, thus may be genuine

Comment: @MrinalKamboj it passes a `byte[]` , so I guess it does *not* stream.

Comment: @Fildor valid point so already streamed

Comment: @KansaiRobot _"Non-blocking background task so that the rest remain responsive"_ this goal should be part of your question. People will possibly miss it in comments.

Answer (score 6):

**EDITED** included all suggestions from the comments and added some background.

#### Background & insights

Converting one function to `async` won't be enough to make the whole process non-blocking. To achieve what you want, the whole processing path (call stack) should be converted to non-blocking. One blocking method on your call stack is enough to render the whole process blocking. *Non-blocking* does not necessarily mean `async`, as some of the examples below will show.

There are two steps involved in converting a method into `async`:

- Change the signature to return `Task`. This will allow your callers track status and outcome of your method.
- Add `async` keyword to the signature. This will allow `await`-ing other `async` methods in the body of your method.

#### CPU-bound vs IO-bound tasks

Note that even when you `await` for a method, it doesn't necessarily mean that you immediately release the thread back to your caller. The method being `await`-ed will release the thread back to you only as soon as it in turn begins `await`-ing for an IO-bound operation. Your thread will still block while the `await`-ed method performs CPU-bound operations before the first time it is `await`-ing for an IO-bound operation.

For example:

```
async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // equivalent to CPU-bound operations
}

await MyAsyncMethod(); // will block for 5 seconds
```

On the other hand,

```
async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000); // equivalent to IO-bound operations
}

await MyAsyncMethod(); // will return immediately
```

And the workaround if you have CPU-bound tasks but still don't want to block the caller thread:

```
async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Yield(); // this does the magic
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // equivalent to CPU-bound operations
}

await MyAsyncMethod(); // will return immediately thanks to Task.Yield()
```

#### What to do in your case

Since I'm not sure why you cannot change OnFrameSampleAcquired signature to `async`, I will suggest several different options.

**Option 1**

The simplest and the truly asynchronous approach would be this:

```
async Task OnFrameSampleAcquired(VideoCaptureSample sample)
{  
    //Some code here

    //Here I want to introduce an Asynchrnous process
    await ProcessAsynchronously(_latestImageBytes);

    //some more code here -- provided it is either async or non-blocking!
}

async Task ProcessAsynchronously(byte[] image)  
{
    await Process1(image);
    await Process2(image);
    // ...
}
```

If all of the methods on your processing path look like these, you have a properly implemented non-blocking background job.

**Option 2**

If you're absolutely unable to change the signature OnFrameSampleAcquired, there is a workaround. You can instead invoke the rest of the processing asynchronously, as suggested by @Fildor:

```
public void OnFrameSampleAcquired(VideoCaptureSample sample)
{
    //Some code here

    //Here I want to introduce an Asynchrnous process
    ProcessAsynchronously(_latestImageBytes).ContinueWith(task => {
        // this runs on a different thread after ProcessAsynchronously is completed
        // some more code here
    });

    // return without blocking
}
```

Here you win on both sides: first, you don't have to change the signature of OnFrameSampleAcquired; second, OnFrameSampleAcquired is now a non-blocking method.

**Option 3**

If you cannot change your signature because you must implement an interface like this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void OnFrameSampleAcquired(VideoCaptureSample sample);
    // ... other members
}
```

then you can add the `async` keyword to your method and still comply with the interface:

```
async void OnFrameSampleAcquired(VideoCaptureSample sample)
{  
    //Some code here

    //Here I want to introduce an Asynchrnous process
    await ProcessAsynchronously(_latestImageBytes);

    //some more code here
}

ISomeInterface x;                  // initialized elsewhere
x.OnFrameSampleAcquired(/*....*/); // the same as await, but no error handling
```

The drawback of this option is that the callers cannot track nor the status of the task (still running or completed?), neither its outcome (completed or threw exception?). You will probably have to wrap the entire body of OnFrameSampleAcquired in a `try/catch`, and write an exception to log.

**Option 4**

Technically, you can also invoke an async ProcessAsynchronously from a non-async OnFrameSampleAcquired using `Wait` on a `Task`, but **it won't achieve your goal of having a non-blocking background task**. The `Wait()` will block the thread until the async processing is done:

```
void OnFrameSampleAcquired(VideoCaptureSample sample)
{  
    //Some code here

    //Here I want to introduce an Asynchrnous process
    ProcessAsynchronously(_latestImageBytes).Wait();

    //some more code here
}
```

Comment: I'd like to see explanation of the downvote. Thank you.

Comment: Guessing: 1. snippet does not solve the problem, 2. snippet: OP stated explicitly, he cannot make OnFrameSampleAcquired use the async keyword. Also it looks like an EventHandler, so making it `async Task` would not apply anyway.

Comment: @Fildor `OnFrameSampleAcquired` is an event is a guess, would have a preferred a syntax like `Object sender, EventArgs args` to be much more convinced

Comment: @felix-b I do up vote to counter the baseless down vote, people shall explain their view and then down vote

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Even if my guess is incorrect, OP stated he cannot do it, still.

Comment: @Fildor in fact I wonder is there a problem to solve here :). Code will simply not work as expected

Comment: _"Code will simply not work as expected"_ - And that is *not* a problem ??

Comment: @Fildor what is the expected behavior in this case? I don't read it anywhere in the question. The question says how to introduce a call to an async method without converting the calling method to async. This is by itself an indication of a probable design problem, but it is outside of scope of the question being answered. What am I missing?

Comment: _"Non-blocking background task so that the rest remain responsive"_ - from OP in comments to the question what he is aiming to achieve. Should have been part of the question, though.

Comment: There is one more option: `async void OnFrameSampleAcquired` and then do the same as in option 1. Important to properly handle all exceptions (wrap whole thing in try-catch block) in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Evk, included in the answer!